# how secure is my random salt generator

Tags: php, security, passwords

I have the following PHP script:

```
<?php

    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV0123456789~`!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]{}:;/.,<>?";
    $salt = str_shuffle($chars);
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 64);s
    echo $salt;

?>
```

Can someone tell me how secure it is? Shouldn't it sort of be secure against brute forcing attacks, because it generates a 64 totally random character string? However, when I tested it, 95% of the time it generates a 64 character string, but sometimes it does not. For example, it generated `` zk;~+1`9t4s7mg[e!JRPI(ob ``, which is only a 24 character string. Another time it generated a 11 character string. Could anybody tell me why this is?

Moving onto its security, how secure is it actually? If it's not very/secure enough, please tell me what alternatives there are.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might be more suitable if posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not as random as using `mcrypt_create_iv()` or `fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb')`. Password salts do not have much to do with security; all passwords should just have *unique* salts. If you want to do it right you should use the [Password extension](http://php.net/password).

Comment: Salts are not generally needed to be *that* secure. Salts are there just to be unique so if two users have the same password, they don't look the same when they are saved in the database. See http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/can-you-help-me-understand-what-a-cryptographic-salt-is

Comment: Is there any reason at all why you don't use the [PHP functions for hashing *and* salting passwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to prevent you from making mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, it generated zk;~+1`9t4s7mg[e!JRPI(ob, which is only a 24 character string. Another time it generated a 11 character string. Could anybody tell me why this is?

Probably not. It's only because of using `<` character and browser think that's tag beginning. For example if you have generated string

```
!KyR<I)/$NPjfd-U*+vpmA9zh2;7#_}JSr(@tH4kFa:[?`l6TD~&w,8LOE5.3Qqc
```

it will show you in browser as `!KyR` but in source you will see the whole string. (If you want to display it use `htmlspecialchars()` function)

> Can someone tell me how secure it is?

Question for me is why don't you use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) that creates salt automatically for given password?

Comment: Indeed it is much better to use the `password_hash()` function! The shown code can only produce a fraction of all possible salts, and some hash-algorithms like BCrypt have restrictions about a valid salt.